# Assoicative Array keys that resolve to numbers return no results

Tags: autohotkey, associative-array

If I loop through the array of strings, and use each string as the key to an associative array, the key that is the string representation of a number cannot "find" its associated value:

```
KeyArray := Array("AAA", "777")
AssocArray := {"AAA":{"Item1":"Item1Value", "Item2":"Item2Value"} 
              ,"777":{"Item1":"Item1Value", "Item2":"Item2Value"}}

Loop % KeyArray.Length() {
    aKey := KeyArray[A_Index]
    aValue := AssocArray[aKey]
    sResult := aKey . ": " . aValue["Item1"] . "`t" . aValue["Item2"]
    ToolTip, % sResult
    OutputDebug % "[AHK] sResult: " . sResult . " " 
    Sleep 5000
}
```

If, however I use a For loop to iterate the keys:

```
For aKey, aValue In AssocArray {
    sResult := aKey . ": " . aValue["Item1"] . "`t" . aValue["Item2"]
    ToolTip, % sResult
    OutputDebug % "[AHK] sResult: " . sResult . " " 
    Sleep 5000
}
```

Then the "777" is recognized as a key, and its values are returned correctly
Alternatively, if I remove the quotes from "777" inboth the KeyArray and AssocArray then both loops find the correct values.

Now to the question:
**How do I correctly use the string representation of a number as a key to an Associative array?**

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with internal type coercion and the caching of numbers.

In other words, string "777" is coerced into number 777 in `AssocArray[aKey]`, as any expression (`aKey` in this case) produces a number if the evaluated result is in a number form, unless explicitly told otherwise.

A workaround:

```
aValue := AssocArray[aKey ""]
```

With the above single-line modification, your first piece of code has been tested to work.

---

**Edit**:

Regarding the question in the comment below, here are some references:

[Caching](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Concepts.htm#caching)
[type coercion aka implicit type conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#Implicit_type_conversion)

Note, however, that ["implicit" and "explicit" are relative terms](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/you-dont-know/9781491905159/ch04.html#converting-values) in the context of coercion.

Comment: Thank you!  That is exactly what I needed.  I could not find this in the help file.
Can you please point to a place where this ability is documented?